# how to use seaborn objects scale with two visualisations with same kwargs?

Tags: seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I'm trying to create bar plot with labels on bars. Position of labels and color of labels depends on column of dataframe. Also, I would like to color bars by column.

My data:

```
data = {
    'Survived': ['0', '1'],
    'count': [500, 100],
    'label_position': ['R', 'L']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to create following plot:

```
import seaborn.objects as so

p = (
    so.Plot(df, x='count', y='Survived')
    .add(so.Bar(alpha=1), color='Survived')
    .add(
            so.Text({"fontweight": "bold"}),
            text='count',
            halign='label_position',
            color="label_position"
        )
    .scale(
        halign={'L':'left', 'R':'right'},
        color={'L':'black', 'R':'white'}
        )
    )
p.plot()
```

but this code raises following error:

```
PlotSpecError: Scale setup failed for the `color` variable. See the traceback above for more information.
```

because both visualizations have attribute color.

I'm able co color bars, or the text, but not both at once.

Colored bars:
[color the bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9shy.png)

Colored text:
[color the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLGs7.png)

Is there any posibility to color both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we `see the traceback above for more information` as the exception message suggests, it says

```
ValueError: No entry in color dictionary for '0', '1'
```

So we could try adding entries for those keys:

```
(
    so.Plot(df, x='count', y='Survived')
    .add(so.Bar(alpha=1), color='Survived')
    .add(
        so.Text({"fontweight": "bold"}),
        text='count',
        halign='label_position',
        color="label_position",
    )
    .scale(
        halign={'L':'left', 'R':'right'},
        color={'L':'black', 'R':'white', '0': 'black', '1': 'white'},  # <-----
    )
)
```

[image]

That works but now we have some entries in the legend that we probably don't want. There's not in general a way to control what shows up in the legend independently of what actually gets mapped for `Nominal` scales, but for this particular plot the color encoding is redundant anyway so we don't  actually need the legend:

```
(
    so.Plot(df, x='count', y='Survived')
    .add(so.Bar(alpha=1), color='Survived', legend=False)  # <-----
    .add(
        so.Text({"fontweight": "bold"}),
        text='count',
        halign='label_position',
        color="label_position",
    )
    .scale(
        halign={'L':'left', 'R':'right'},
        color={'L':'black', 'R':'white', '0': 'black', '1': 'white'},
    )
)
```

[image]